# Better design pattern for implementing ever changing components

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Background:
The product has the following classes (entities):

1. Module
2. Department
3. Layout
4. Field

The relationships goes like this:

- Module can be department specific or not.
- Module has layout.
- Layout has Fields.
- Fields can be of many types. (Number, Line, DropDown, etc.)
- Fields are module specific. That means field and layouts of module has many to many relationship.
- Fields normally have module specific properties which clients use via one api.
- There is another api that renders layouts and their corresponding fields. These have few extra details (like whether the field is mandatory in the module or not, etc.)

Problem: I need to refactor this entire sub system into proper design and make proper classes such that it solves our current use case and also for future use cases.

Currently, we have two classes for fields. One to show only module specific details and type specific details. Another that shows these along with layout specific details.

I don't want to duplicate this much of code. So, I have came up with 2 solutions:

- Make an abstract class for fields which contains all the properties common to all field types. Then for each field type, create a new field. In this way, new types can be added easily.
  Also keep a bunch of interfaces as strategies - LayoutProperties, License, etc. This approach looks good but feels like slowly the abstract class will turn into god class.
- Similar to above. Create abstract classes and put common details. And create different class for sub classes. But Create a separate interface like LayoutDetails. Each field type is then again extended to create a new field which also has layout related properties.

Both approach seem to be workable but doesn't seem clean to me. Can anyone advise on whether I am on the right track or I am missing any design pattern that will be better suited for this problem. I can share some basic code if it will help.

Edit:
Why change now?
Currently we have many requests for different new types of fields. So working with the old code is becoming too difficult. There are already too many if checks (if this type, then do that, else do something else). I want to get a polymorphic solution for these issues. And I want to reduce code duplication to as low as possible.
Let us take an example. Suppose, I want to introduce a new type of field like unique field. This will be field type built on top of the existing types.. Now, all field types won't be having unique field properties. So, I need to add properties of uniqueness in the main pojo and in CRUD operations, need to do if checks to see if the type of field. My goal is to avoid that.

Comment: I think first you should explain the need for making changes.  "If it ain't broke don't fix it" is an old software adage.  The next step would be to explain "our current use case" and what isn't working.  And finally "also for future use cases." is never a solvable problem and any attempts to do so are usually considered [gold plating.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_(project_management))

Comment: As for your two solutions you might also look at the Composite Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: @markspace please check the edit I have added to answer your question

Comment: Well your use case seems very complicated, so I don't know if anyone can offer an actual solution.  I see you have an actual reason for change, so that's fine.  The next thing that occurs to me is that your code seems very similar to a GUI, so you could look at working GUI code to find ideas for simplification.  I'd suggest you get a library that handles GUI code. "Don't reinvent the wheel." And Composite Pattern is a GUI pattern btw.

Comment: Another thing that occurs to me is that many GUIs separate their code into a Model and a View, where the Model handles the type of updates allowed and processes correct answers and such.  This allows more complex ideas by separating concerns.  Also many GUI classes are rather complicated and handle a fairly wide variety of uses.  Rather than just one thing they can be configured to handle a variety of common uses (unique vs. multiple selections, for example) and that might be one way to reduce the complexity of too many classes required.

Comment: @markspace looking into GUI code seems to be a good alternative. Will look into it. Thank you for the suggestion